# mysqli_store_result() vs. mysqli_use_result()

Tags: php, mysqli

## The question

What is the difference between [`mysqli::store_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php) and [`mysqli::use_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php)?

## The story

#### Vague documentation

The documentation on PHP.net seems very vague about the difference between the two. The [`mysqli::use_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php)-page does not offer any code-samples, and links you to the [`mysqli::multi_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)-page to look for them. In that page the following code-sample is given (see the page for the full code):

```
/* store first result set */
if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
    }
    $result->free();
}
/* print divider */
if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
    printf("-----------------\n");
}
```

The [`mysqli::store_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php)-page uses *exactly* the same code-sample, with one exception:

```
/* store first result set */
if ($result = $mysqli->use_result()) {
```

Yeah... `store_result` became `use_result`. Note that even the comment above is still saying "store".

#### Even more confusing

Having seen the code samples, I thought; "all right, so it's an alias". But wait! The documentation gives the following descriptions:

- [mysqli_store_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php) — Transfers a result set from the last query
- [mysqli_use_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php) — Initiate a result set retrieval

They seem like two different things, and are not brought like aliases at all. Taking a closer look I found out that there was yet another exception in the code-sample of the [`mysqli::use_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php)-page: `$result->free();` became `$result->close();`. However my hopes for finding out the truth were soon after shattered, when I found that on that same page in the second code sample (the procedural equivalent), `mysqli_free_result($result);` was used, and not the expected `mysqli_close_result($result);`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`mysqli::store_result()` will fetch the whole resultset from the MySQL server while `mysqli::use_result()` will fetch the rows one by one.

This is also mentioned in the `mysqli::use_result` docs you linked to:

> The mysqli_use_result() function does not transfer the entire result set from the database and hence cannot be used functions such as mysqli_data_seek() to move to a particular row within the set. To use this functionality, the result set must be stored using mysqli_store_result(). One should not use mysqli_use_result() if a lot of processing on the client side is performed, since this will tie up the server and prevent other threads from updating any tables from which the data is being fetched.

You can usually always use `mysqli::store_result()` unless you have a good reason for not reading all rows from the server at once.

Comment: Ah, so basically doing subsequent `use_result` calls is a lot more heavy because php will have to query the server for every result in the resultset, while with `store_result` all of the results will be stored on the php-side after the first call, and subsequent calls will just request the results from php?

Comment: Yes, that pretty much sums it up.

Comment: I just love the example on php.net with the comment `If we have to retrieve large amount of data we use MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` what is classified as a `large amount of data`? This term is very relative A small amount of data from say Amazon's database would be larger than my entire 5 Mb database.

Comment: Ok, so what does `get_result` do?

Comment: @amaster507 just found interesting Note at [mysqli::store_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php) page at Return Values section: `... returning FALSE after successful call to mysqli_query() can be too large result set (memory for it cannot be allocated)` which means if you have not enough memory to buffer all of the expected data you should use [mysqli::use_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php)

Answer (score 16):

`use_result` returns an **unbuffered** result.

`store_result` returns a **buffered** result.

Comment: What is PHP's default method? For instance, if I do not execute store_result() or use_result() before execute() and fetch() on a prepared statement. I'm assuming use_result(), since there is no use_result() on a mysqli_stmt object.

Comment: @crush NO, the default is MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT

Comment: @crush `mysqli_prepare` is **unbuffered** by default (use mysqli_stmt::store_result or mysqli_stmt::get_result for buffered)
`pdo_prepare` is **buffered** by default (use `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false)` for unbuffered)
`mysqli_query` and `pdo_query` are **buffered** by default

Answer (score 0):

I think this elaboration might help people getting here from languages that support retrieving either via arrays or enumerators. Because it is just that difference.

For .NET, it would be the same difference as [GetDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58.aspx) (store_results) vs [EnumerateDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413235.aspx) (use_results) (and the File/DbResult/CSV parsing/XML Parsing equivalents).

The enumerator variant uses less (PHP) client memory and might fetch the next row asynchronously in the background while the current row is processing, making it both more memory and processing time effective on the client side. At the cost of taking up (SQL) Server resources for longer (as the result set has not been fully transmitted).

In turn the get/array way will retrieve the data in one blocking operation, taking up more client side memory for freeing DB memory earlier.

Personally I would default for the non-Enumerator Way, unless you actually got (client) memory issues.

In .NET you have to use the Enumerator way, if you run into the 2/3 GiB limit for x32 processes. Particular EnumerateLines for files is important here.
With DB results it should not happen to begin with. A 2 GiB DB result is either **way** under-filtered (do more filtering in Query) or contains a lot of Blobs (which you should load piecemeal or even let the browser retrieve via a http handler if possible).