# PHP: SHOW TABLES with MYSQLI_USE_RESULT not work

Tags: php, mysqli

Like in theme. In query :

```
$query = $link->query('SHOW TABLES LIKE "table"',MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
```

and check like:

```
echo $query->num_rows;
```

always shows 0
I mention $query->close(); don't help.

Actually voted as documentation bug :
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74262

Comment: surely you're using MYSQLI_USE_RESULT on purpose, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, if I remove MYSQLI_USE_RESULT everything works fine !
 ~Fred -ii - query checked not failed...

Comment: You make opinion too fast...

Comment: So even after all these explanations you decided to waste PHP team's time with your silly bogus complaint. That's sad.

Comment: For my stupid explanation what you provided, this is sad, there is no bad questions only bad answers, think about this...

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong that's why.

```
$result = $link->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'table'");
$rows = $result->num_rows;

echo $rows;
```

Procedural:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SHOW TABLES LIKE 'table'");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo $rows;
```

Comment: Yes it works that way but with MYSQLI_USE_RESULT -not, why ?

Comment: @DarofromPoland because it's how MYSQLI_USE_RESULT exactly works?

Comment: Don't understand you , You suggest that MYSQLI_USE_RESULT works not showing any rows in mysqli_result ?

Comment: @DarofromPoland MYSQLI_USE_RESULT works exactly as it's described in the manual. Either you are using it on purpose, and therefore have an idea on what are you doing, or just leave this option alone.

Comment: refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876730/mysqli-store-result-vs-mysqli-use-result

Comment: In manual describes to use with big data in mysqli_result received by query, to force to clear mysqli_result by close() or free(), for beter control of memory, like I understand. Other way always after query with MYSQLI_USE_RESULT You should clear mysqli_result. But it not works.

Comment: @DarofromPoland 1. SHOW TABLES result nowhere is any big. 2. What you want after all - the number of rows or actual table names? If the latter **then just fetch them!**

Comment: Simple checking if is one row. SHOW dont shows number of tables(rows) even if there is no tables it returns true or false(casting in if) only if query fails. For checking if is that table we must check by num_rows property of mysqli_result object. With MYSQLI_USE_RESULT is 0 , without is 1, in my case.

Comment: @DarofromPoland frankly, FORGET about MYSQLI_USE_RESULT. Leave it alone

Comment: :) but why ?...

Comment: @DarofromPoland, Read the documentation on php.net if you don't understand why. It's clearly explained. It's not for small result sets.

Comment: @DarofromPoland simply because it doesn't work for you