# What does the 'type' property in the mysqli_result object represent?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

let's say I have this variable:

```
$my_query_object = $previous_connection->query($my_query);
```

that `mysqli_result` object according to php.net has several methods AND these properties:

```
int $current_field ;
int $field_count;
array $lengths;
int $num_rows;
```

cool.. but if I

```
print_r($my_query_object)
```

I get this property `[type] => 0` at the end of the object description

**Question 1:**
what is this property and why it wasn't mentioned in the `mysqli_result` page?!

**Question 2:**
how can I print/echo/log/list the METHODS and PROPERTIES of an object 
and if I can't do both together (print properties and methods in one command) at least how can I print the methods of an object, got tired of going back and forth to php.net just to check the object's anatomy..

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after a bit of research I found that

`[type] => 0` represents `MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT` constant 
`[type] => 1` represents `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` constant 
for more information about the behaviour of these constants check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876730/mysqli-store-result-vs-mysqli-use-result).

In contrast to ***Obsidian Age***'s answer the number doesn't represent the type of the array and whether it's associative or numeric but the `resultmode` of the `query()` method

Answer (score 3):

This is best explained in the docs for **[`fetch-all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)**:

> *`resulttype`*
>
> This optional parameter is a constant indicating what type of array should be produced from the current row data. The possible values for this parameter are the constants `MYSQLI_ASSOC`, `MYSQLI_NUM`, or `MYSQLI_BOTH`.

To get the properties of an object, you can use **[`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)**:

> ```
> class foo {
>    private $a;
>    public $b = 1;
>    public $c;
>    private $d;
>    static $e;
>   
>    public function test() {
>        var_dump(get_object_vars($this));
>    }
> }
>
> $test = new foo;
> var_dump(get_object_vars($test));
>
> $test->test();
> ```